# C++: How to Block .msc and .cpl type applications?

Tags: c++, windows, hook

I am currently developing an application for Windows for Admin Privilege Control. As part of this, I have already developed a program that blocks EXE files by hooking CreateProcessInternalW API.

On Proceeding further, I have the following doubts:
1. How to block .msc files (For instance, say Services.Msc)
2. How to Block .cpl files (For Instance, say Firewall.cpl)

I do not want to work on the registry level. I want to know if there are any other ways to do these tasks, at Kernel Level

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself after some working out.
lpCommandLine parameter contains the path for all the control panel and Windows items, that is passed as parameter for mmc.exe and control.exe respectively during createprocess() call, in this case services.msc and firewall.cpl

Please do correct me if this approach is wrong!